# "missing boundary headers" with ws.url in scala play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

I'm testing a service against a dummy endpoint, with the following code:

```
ws.url(dummyService).withHeaders(HeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE -> "multipart/form-data; boundary=-----{}}AAA{{}-----").post(myData)
```

This generates the request ok, the headers are set properly.

In my mock service, I process the response like so:

```
def checkData = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body.files.find(_.filename.endsWith("testfail.pdf")) match {
      case Some(invalidFile) => BadRequest("Parse Fail")
      case None => Ok("Parse Success")
    }
  }
```

When I run the test, I get an error 400, and the following message:

```
For request 'POST /TEST/process' [Missing boundary header]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use `Action(parse.multipartFormData)` you have to make sure that the corresponding POST request is using a form encoding of `multipart/form-data` ([more on when to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/1804173)).

In other words you would want to define the form in your template like this:

```scala
@helper.form(action = routes.MyApp.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
  // ...
}
```

Sending a POST with a different encoding results in the `[Missing boundary header]` error.